# Confused by Android access control mechanism. It's DIFFERENT from java

Tags: java, android, access-control

In java, subclass cannot override default or private method from base class if not in the same package.
The base class code:

```
//base class
public class TestBase {
protected void test() {
    defaultTest();
    protectedTest();
    privateTest();
}

void defaultTest() {
    System.out.println("defaultTest");
}

protected void protectedTest() {
    System.out.println("protectedTest");
}

private void privateTest() {
    System.out.println("privateTest");
}
}
```

and subclass code:

```
public class TestImpl extends TestBase {
protected void test() {
    super.test();
    localTest();
}

private void localTest() {
    System.out.println("Impl:localTest");
}
protected void defaultTest() {
    System.out.println("Impl:defaultTest");
}

protected void protectedTest() {
    System.out.println("Impl:protectedTest");
}

public void privateTest() {
    System.out.println("Impl:privateTest");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestImpl().test();
}
}
```

let us put them into different package,and the output is:

```
defaultTest
Impl:protectedTest
privateTest
Impl:localTest
```

This reflects access control mechanism in java. We cannot override the defaultTest() mehod in subclass. But in andorid, we can!
In the android.widget.AdapterView class, there is a default method:

```
void checkSelectionChanged() {
    if ((mSelectedPosition != mOldSelectedPosition) || (mSelectedRowId != mOldSelectedRowId)) {
        selectionChanged();
        mOldSelectedPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        mOldSelectedRowId = mSelectedRowId;
    }
}
```

So any subclass in the same package, such as Spinner, can invoke the checkSelectionChanged() method. And then OnItemSelectedListener is called. We can add our own lister to listen the event and we will be notified the change.
However if we extend Spinner, say CustomSpinner, and define the same method in the CustomSpinner, as the code:

```
public class CustomSpinner  extends Spinner{

public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle,
        int mode) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle, mode);
}

public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomSpinner(Context context, int mode) {
    super(context, mode);
}

public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

void checkSelectionChanged() {
    Log.i("CustomSpinner", "Called!");
}
}
```

Then strange thing is the checkSelectionChanged() in CustomSpinner is called and our listener never be notified. This is caused by overriding. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure, but I thought overriding a method meant the access modifier has to be the same for both the super and subclass methods. That's not the case in your example.

Comment: In fact, I get the same result whichever modifier is defined in the subclass class.

Comment: @gsingh2011 Same or wider access modifier...

Comment: IT simply cannot be. Google only made a custom JVM, not a custom language spec. I'm not clear why you think android enforce different access rules but can you explain what you think happens in android with your test classes?

Comment: @Thihara I just repalce android.widget.Spinner with my CustomSpinner. My method checkSelectionChanged() is called without any my code calling it. Android Spinner wakes up any registered OnItemSelectedListener through calling checkSelectionChanged() internally. I think my checkSelectionChanged() should not be called to influence the internal logic in android because in java my checkSelectionChanged() should not be the overriding code and is just local in my CustomSpinner, as the java test class shows

Answer (score 1):

Access control is exactly the same in Android and Java.

There is no `onSelectionChanged()` method in [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) -- not `public` or `protected` at least. If there is a package-private method like this, you *can* override it, but only if your class is in the same package, and it's not. You have simply declared an unrelated method with the same name; it is not overriding.

This is why you should use `@Override` where you intend to override a method. It would have generated a compile error that would tell you you are not actually overriding.

Comment: Actually I have no code to call my onSelectionChanged(), but why it IS called and android internal onSelectionChanged() never be called?

Comment: In java, i know it is not overriding. So i think this is a stupid feature in android. And it is dangerous when i define a same mothod as android `default` method unmeantly. It influences android internal logic but i get no message.